# Can anyone help me on how to fetch MySQL table/s data in JSON format by querying itself which is similar to MS SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Below is the existing T-SQL code which generates table data in JSON format just by using the keyword **`FOR JSON PATH`**, **`include_null_value`**.

How to implement the same in MySQL query itself???  Need possible solutions.

/** Sample Table data in MS SQL server ***/

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
                              [id]    INT,
                              [name]  VARCHAR(25),
                              [state] VARCHAR(25) 
                             )


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee] values
(1,'SwapnaS','Bangalore'),
(2,'Divya','Hyderabad'),
(3,'Akshaya','Delhi'),
(4,'Rajini',NULL)
```

/** Fetching table data in JSON format ***/

```
DECLARE @json1 NVARCHAR(Max) 
SET @json1 = (
              SELECT * 
                FROM dbo.Employee WITH(nolock)
                 FOR JSON PATH, include_null_values 
)
SELECT ',' AS [key],[value] 
  FROM OPENJSON(@json1)

/** MS SQL results to **/
```

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| , | {"id":4,"name":"Rajini","state":null} |
| , | {"id":1,"name":"Swapna","state":"Bangalore"} |
| , | {"id":2,"name":"Divya","state":"Hyderabad"} |
| , | {"id":3,"name":"Akshaya","state":"Delhi"} |

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`JSON_OBJECT()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html) function such as

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
                   'id',id , 
                   'name',name,
                   'state',state
                   ) AS value
  FROM Employee
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ca88ee3c7d173566384238b9a8d51053)</kbd>